# How do I get the CurrentPassword when I am doing a ChangePassword call in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, change-password

What is the current password when a user has logged in using a temporary password after a password reset email was sent. I want to do a password change but I keep getting an INVALID_PASSWORD error type.

I am using your sample code for changing passwords but I can't find a way to get the current password.

Answer (score 2):

After sending a password reset email via the client library, you can use the password reset token from the email as the 'current password' for the purposes of changing the password.